# Is NSBlockOperation serial?

Tags: objective-c, nsblockoperation

We can keep adding block after block. Will those be executed serially?

I can't think of any reason why it's not. Nothing is specific.

This is not NSOperationQueue. This is NSBlockOperation that also can have several blocks

Comment: What do you mean by "We can keep adding block after block." Also, you cannot rely upon multiple block operations executing serially (when used independently of a queue).

Comment: You can use  -(void)addExecutionBlock:(void (^)(void))block to add block to an NSBlockOperation.

Comment: See this note from the documentation: "Blocks added to a block operation are dispatched with default priority to an appropriate work queue. The blocks themselves should not make any assumptions about the configuration of their execution environment." The work queue may or may not be a serial queue.